# Can we have more than one .edmx file in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am newbie in Entity framework. In my application I have so many tables. I have just implemented CRUD for one module i.e. (For UserMaster). Now I have to implement same for other modules as well.
Can you please tell me should i used only one .edmx file for all the tables or different .edmx file for different module will work?
I search a lot on internet... and they suggest to use different files... but I dont know how to use it... Also I didn't get any sample example for this...
Can you please help me????

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple diagrams per model in Entity Framework >= 5.0

http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/using-multiple-diagrams-per-model-in-entity-framework-5-0

Otherwise, another way is to completely get rid of edmx file which is far better with the help of code first.